# gtk treeview: place image buttons on rows

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, gtktreeview

For each row in my treeview, I want 4 image buttons next to each other. They will act like radio buttons, with only one being activateable at a time. Each button has an 'on' and 'off' image.

How do I do this? I figured out how to put images there, and how to put togglebuttons, but this seems to require some more effort as there is no pre-built cellrenderer that does what I want.

Basically what'd solve my problem is figuring out how to make an image in a `gtk.treeview` clickable. any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this ['http://www.daa.com.au/pipermail/pygtk/2010-March/018355.html'](http://www.daa.com.au/pipermail/pygtk/2010-March/018355.html).  It shows you how to make a gtk.CellRendererPixbuf activatable, and able to connect to a click event signal.

```
cell = CellRendererPixbufXt()
cell.connect('clicked', func)
```

Update

As pointed out this answer, or the reference given doesn't work as advertised. It's missing the do_activate method, which  needs to emit the clicked signal. Once it's done that, then the cell.connect will work.

Sorry if this answer mislead anyone.

Comment: I don't know what you're looking at but my reference does.  I notice your answer does pretty much the same thing as the reference I gave. If you're complaining about something else, please be a little clearer

Comment: The `clicked` signal is never triggered. Actually, this isn't a big surprise if I quote from your reference: "but i'm not sure how to emit the custom "clicked" signal, when the user clicks
on the CellRenderer."

Comment: At least your're being clearer now.  Why you didn't say this in the first place.  I'll check it out when I have the time, but it's been over a year, so I'm in no hurry.  I'm surprised it got accepted in the first place if it doesn't work.

Comment: The link is down. You could you extend your answer, please?

Comment: I think the answer below mine by schlamar is a better answer and gives an example. Really it should be marked as the correct answer, not mine. Honestly I've not touched GTK for a few years now.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a short version without `kiwi` requirement.

```
class CellRendererClickablePixbuf(gtk.CellRendererPixbuf):

    __gsignals__ = {'clicked': (gobject.SIGNAL_RUN_LAST, gobject.TYPE_NONE,
                                (gobject.TYPE_STRING,))
                   }

    def __init__(self):
        gtk.CellRendererPixbuf.__init__(self)
        self.set_property('mode', gtk.CELL_RENDERER_MODE_ACTIVATABLE)

    def do_activate(self, event, widget, path, background_area, cell_area,
                    flags):
        self.emit('clicked', path)
```

Comment: I'm trying to use your code  but I'm getting `gi.repository.Gtk' object has no attribute 'CELL_RENDERER_MODE_ACTIVATABLE'` - any ideas why?

Comment: @pawel.ad - Only 8 years too late, but `CELL_RENDERER_MODE_ACTIVATABLE` is from GTK2

Answer (score 1):

Here is what worked for me:

```
class CellRendererClickablePixbuf(gtk.CellRendererPixbuf):
    gsignal('clicked', str)
    def __init__(self):
        gtk.CellRendererPixbuf.__init__(self)
        self.set_property('mode', gtk.CELL_RENDERER_MODE_ACTIVATABLE)
    def do_activate(self, event, widget, path, background_area, cell_area, flags):
        self.emit('clicked', path)
```

Comment: I assume you refer to `kiwi.utils.gsignal`?