# How to implement activate() function on gtk.CellRendererPixbuf in PyGTK?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, gtk2

As far as I know, only `gtk.CellRendererToggle` and `gtk.CellRendererText` can be activated. I have a `gtk.CellRendererPixbuf` in a `gtk.TreeView` which I want to make it emit a signal when clicked.

I read that the `activate()` function can do the job but I do not know how to implement it.

`def activate(event, widget, path, background_area, cell_area, flags)`

What does each of these arguments mean and how do I set/obtain them? Any examples would be extremely helpful.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/4940351/851737

Comment: I'm not sure I'd call it a duplicate, the answer can be found there but the question is different.

Answer (score 2):

I have not tried this myself before, but your question has been asked before, maybe this is of some help for you:

[gtk treeview: place image buttons on rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940351/gtk-treeview-place-image-buttons-on-rows)

Comment: Indeed is a great help. Will look into it in the morrow.